# ng-repeat binding breaks with Parse.Cloud.run()

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, parse-platform, angularjs-ng-repeat

To summarise the problem:

- using AngularJS 1.3.15
- using Parse.com library 1.4.2
- onscreen **output bound to my controller is not updating** when the underlying structure does update

---

My HTML is simple - I use `ng-repeat` to output characters from an array in my controller:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

    <div ng-repeat="char in main.chars">
        {{char}}
    </div>
</body>
```

---

To populate this array, I have 2 factory services.

- `httpFactory` reads from a local JSON file using `$http.get(...)`
- `parseFactory` reads from Parse Cloud Code using `Parse.Cloud.run(...)`
- they are otherwise essentially identical

Both of these are succeeding, and expose a result using a Promise i.e. `.then(...)`

```
app.factory('httpFactory', function($http) {
    return {
        getArray: function () {
            return $http.get('/data/beaches.json').then(
                function(response){
                    var array = ["Y", "e", "s"];
                    return array;
                });
        }
    };
});

app.factory('parseFactory', function() {
    return {
        getArray: function () {
            return Parse.Cloud.run('hello').then(
                function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    var array = ["N", "o"];
                    return array;
                });
        }
    };
});
```

Note that in this example, I am returning hard-coded values in the promises, to rule out any issues with the webservices themselves.

There is nothing special about the Parse Cloud function. It is from the basic template - function `hello` correctly returns the expected "Hello, world!".

---

My controller, `MainCtrl` is very simple. I instantiate the `chars` array with an initial value.

I call into each factory service in turn, using the return values to update my `chars` array, which I log out after the update is made.

The call to `httpFactory.getArray()` as this works exactly as expected:

- `chars` array is correctly updated
- bound HTML display changes (from "Init" to "Yes")
- console log output is "HTTP --> Y,e,s"
- I have commented this out to rule out any interactions from this code block

The call to `parseFactory.getArray()` works *mostly* as expected:

- `chars` array is correctly updated
- console log output is "PARSE -> N,o"

**But the bound HTML display does not change.**

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['httpFactory', 'parseFactory', function(httpFactory, parseFactory){
    var main = this;
    main.chars = ["I", "n", "i", "t"];

    // httpFactory.getArray().then(function(arrHttp){
    //     main.chars = arrHttp;
    //     console.log("HTTP --> " + main.chars);
    // });

parseFactory.getArray().then(function(arrParse){
    main.chars = arrParse;
    console.log("PARSE -> " + main.chars);
});
```

---

According to the documentation, `Parse.Cloud.run()` [supports Promises](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html#.run). From the console log output, that seems to be the case.

But the bound output doesn't update.

**Is this an issue with AngularJS, Parse, or the way I'm using them?**

[(full code can be found here)](https://gist.github.com/mobiRic/6131871a764b006ca9fa)

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mIiLdtBw1QJGJRc1ffye?p=preview)

---

### Update

I have logged this issue with Parse as a bug. Will update this post with feedback from their side.

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/833660386703624/

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this weird behavior, but binding started working after adding `$scope` dependency inside `MainCtrl` controller

**Code**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['httpFactory', 'parseFactory', '$scope',
  function(httpFactory, parseFactory, $scope) {
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0mkz6x3TvNXJylZGWVMs?p=preview)

Comment: Interestingly, I have Plunker working with the original code?! After adding `$scope` it starts working, and after removing `$scope` it keeps working. Do you think this could be browser dependant? I was using Chrome, but tried on IE and no luck; not working either way. Looks like it works in Plunker, but not in a real browser.

Comment: Unfortunately I run this through "gulp", which I think uses "node.js"; adding `$scope` doesn't help.

Comment: I'll look at it whenever I will be in front of machine

Comment: note [my workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30615319/383414) - when I call their API with $http it all works. Suggests an issue with Parse itself, not sure if its worth spending too much time on this, unless you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `Parse.Cloud.run()`, use their [REST API for calling Cloud Functions](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions).

They give the following example code:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 4vwhWtM5Sf3ExRvXMkRI04jJj8r2ZETuBQYhiYGo" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: EX6MWjSEblsrHsJCqBZ1AevuTKz0ZlWLHPMloZqD" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
```

Based on that, I have modified `parseFactory` to use `$http` instead of `Parse.Cloud.run()`:

```
app.factory('parseFactory', function($http) {
    return {
        getArray: function () {
            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello',
                headers: {
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id': '4vwhWtM5Sf3ExRvXMkRI04jJj8r2ZETuBQYhiYGo',
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'EX6MWjSEblsrHsJCqBZ1AevuTKz0ZlWLHPMloZqD',
                },
                data: {},
            };

            var parsePromise = $http(request).then(
                function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    var array = ["F", "i", "x", "e", "d"];
                    return array;
                });
            return parsePromise;
        }
    };
});
```

This works exactly as expected.

Comment: do you feel like there is an issue with `Parse.Cloud.run()`

Comment: @pankajparkar that is my belief. The only difference between the working code, and the broken code is `Parse.Cloud.run()`.